# Google App Engine https not working with custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I have custom domain which is verified and added to my Google App Engine app.  HTTP works with the custom domain but HTTPS does not. Eg. 'https://www.example.com' is unreachable. It should map to
'https://myapp.appspot.com', which is reachable and providing a valid certificate.

Any idea how I get HTTPS to work so that 'https://www.example.com' maps to 'https://myapp.appspot.com' ?

Thanks

Custom domain verified and added to GAE https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5uaX.jpg

DNS records added for my domain https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iYRC.jpg

Unreachable error in Chrome screen grab https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdPpu.jpg

Trying to map subdomain www. https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Ksa.jpg

Comment: There is a bunch of reason this could not be working. Provide more details of how you configured your domains.

Comment: You're right of course. I followed the instructions as in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains but I have no idea why HTTP works but HTTPS does not.  I'm hoping someone may have had a similar experience which they solved.

Comment: Interesting, it seems everything is correctly configured. Can you show the error message you get when accessing with the custom domain?

Comment: I'm not a DNS expert so thank you for trying to help.  So, I removed my domain name form my GAE app, re-verified it and added back to the app.   This has had some good effect.  HTTPS now works with the naked domain eg. https: //example.com maps to https: //myapp.appspot.com.   But https: //www.example.com  is  still unreachable. (Error: 35 - OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL).  I would like all www.example.com requests (http or https) to go to https: //myapp.appspot.com.

Answer (score 0):

naked domain - ‘http://example.com’ is different from a sub sub-domain - ‘http://www.example.com’.

You have to map each of them to your appspot.com domain and enable Google Managed SSL for each of them

Updates (based on your comments)

1. App Engine > Settings > custom domains
2. Click on ‘Add a custom domain‘
3. Select your domain name (example.com)
4. Click on continue
5. Now enter [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in the text box
6. Click on Save Mapping and then Continue

Comment: Both naked domain and the www sub-domain work for HTTP requests.    But HTTPS  does not work for the www sub-domain.     eg. 'HTTPS: //www.example.com' is unreachable.  So I'm still not sure how to get all requests to map 'https: //myapp.appspot.com'

Comment: Your first screenshot only shows one domain being mapped in your App Engine console. Just to be clear - are you saying that console currently has a mapping for both the naked and sub domains? Are you also saying both of these mappings have Google Enabled SSL turned on?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. My GAE console shows  only one custom domain 'mydomain.com'. But if I try and add 'www.mydomain.com' its say it's already verified by me.   Also the GAE docs for mapping custom domains state: "Enter your naked domain name (such as "example.com") and click Verify.
Even if you only want to map a subdomain, such as "www.example.com", enter the naked domain name to verify ownership."   As I've said, http requests via www. do work but not https via www.   I've only added the records shown in my GAE console to my DNS, are there some additional records I need to add?

Comment: Replying from a phone so can’t check it myself but unless things have changed, you should have 2 rows on that page. See bullets 1 & 2 of my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66254565/mapping-google-app-engine-with-google-domains/66268646#66268646

Comment: I only have one row for 'mydomain.com'   but when I try and add www.mydomain.com it says its already verified but its not listed as a custom domain.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the steps you have to take. Tried that for our website - https://nocommandline.com and it worked

Comment: Thank you for the extra instructions. I tried this but it fails saying 'www.mydomain.com' is already mapped to project. I've added screen grab to my original posted question.

Comment: Its only GAE project I have with a mapped domain.    Also,   "http:// www.mydomain.com" does map to my project (its only https that is unreachable).  If "www. mydomain.com" was mapped to another project then "http: //www.mydomain.com" wouldn't work as expected?  All very strange.